# The definition of Residue

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

In Wikipedia the definition of a residue of a function $f$ in a point $a$ is a unique value $R$ such that $f(z)-\frac{R}{z-a}$ has an anti derivative in a punctured disk $0<|z-a|<\delta$. How is this equivalent to the $-1$ coefficient of the Laurent series of $f$ around $a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every other term in the Laurent series around $a$ has an anti-derivative. What $-\frac{R}{z-a}$ does in your expression is remove the one term in the Laurent series which *doesn't* have an anti-derivative, namely the degree $-1$ term.